# On SQL Server (2008), if I want to filter a string field that starts with something, what is the best way?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-like

On several SQL queries I need to check if a field starts with a character.
There are several ways to do it, which one is better in performance/standard?

I usually use

```
tb.field LIKE 'C%'
```

but I can also use

```
LEFT(LTRIM(tb.Field),1) = 'C'
```

I know well the uses of each case, but not in terms of performance.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I imagine the first example, because in the second you are doing a trim and then going over all the results again to find 'C'

Comment: Good question, but the best way to find this out is to view their actual execution plans and see where they are different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd go with the first one `LIKE C%`, it'll use an index on the field if there is one rather than having to do a full table scan.

If you really need to include the whitespace `LTRIM` trimming in the query, you could create a persisted computed column with the value `LEFT(LTRIM(tb.Field), 1)` and put an index on it.

Answer (score 4):

`LIKE 'C%'` is going to perform better than a `LEFT(LTRIM())`.

The `LIKE` predicate can still use a supporting index to get at the data you're looking for. I

However, when SQL Server encounters `LEFT(LTRIM(tb.Field), 1) = 'C'`, the database can't determine what you mean. In order to perform a match, SQL Server must scan every row, `LTRIM` the data and then examine the first character. The end result is, most likely, a full table scan.

Answer (score 0):

The first query is just a bit than the other. I've measured it with my query speed measurement script.
Try it yourself:

```
DECLARE @Measurements TABLE(
    MeasuredTime INT NOT NULL
)

DECLARE @ExecutionTime INT
DECLARE @TimesMeasured INT
SET @TimesMeasured = 0


WHILE @TimesMeasured < 1000
BEGIN
    DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME

    SET @StartTime = GETDATE()

    -- your select .. or what every query 

    INSERT INTO @Measurements
    SELECT  DATEDIFF(millisecond, @StartTime, getdate())

    SET @TimesMeasured = @TimesMeasured + 1
END

SELECT @AvgTime = AVG(MeasuredTime) FROM @Measurements
```